# Format list to only include "super strings"

Tags: python

I would like to format the list

```
['wing', 'westwing', 'little', 'little steve', 'spam']
```

To include only

```
['westwing', 'little steve', 'spam']
```

The word 'wing' is dropped because it is a substring of westwing and likewise 'little' is dropped because of 'little steve'. In my project, the superstrings contain more information.

To be specific, the criteria for dropping a word w is that another word v contains w and len(w) < len(v).

Comment: What have you tried in order to solve this problem?

Comment: And what's the criteria for dropping words? Is it `x` word was found in `y` sentence and `len(x) < len/y)` or what determines which of the two gets dropped? why isn't `westwing` dropped because it contains `wing` which was there first?

Comment: It is not an assignment. I have extracted city names from old documents and some cities are specific versions like "west new york".

Comment: So I am guessing you would want to drop `west new york` in case there is already `new york`? That doesn't match your question

Comment: no, i want to drop new york and keep west new york.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will remove all shortest words that are substrings of other items in list:

```
lst = ['wing', 'westwing', 'little', 'little steve', 'spam']

l, out = sorted(lst, key=len, reverse=True), []
while l:
    item = l.pop()
    if all(not item in i for i in l):
        out.append(item)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['spam', 'westwing', 'little steve']
```